# Will the generalist badge be implemented in Meta?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges, meta, generalist-badge

It doesn't look like anyone has received the Generalist badge on Meta.  Will this be implemented here at some date?

Comment: //This set me to peaking at the tag badges, where I was amused to note that someone appears to have had a silver in [status-declined] at some point.

Comment: @dmckee, I think Shog9 has that one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> One thing the badge doesn’t say, is that there must be at least **200 questions in all 40 of the top tags** before this badge is awarded to anyone. That’s why you won’t see it on meta for a bit longer []. I don’t feel you can accurately measure a generalist until the top tag list settles down.

From https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/

OData is not my strong suit, but here's an [attempt at a query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/513/is-the-site-ready-for-the-generalist-badge).

Comment: Looks like another 5 months to go on Meta.

Comment: Quick! Someone start asking more questions about `[asking-questions]`! Just [58 to go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions)!